# Highcharts: Chart does not resize properly by making the screen smaller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am using HighCharts 4.0.4 and I have a chart with a custom legend in this way:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="legend">
        Legend
    </div>
</div>
```

The `CSS` looks like this. The `wrapper` is a table, so that I can use in the legend with `table-cell` a `vertical-align: middle`. I want to have both 50% of the width of the `wrapper`.

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}

.legend {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#chart {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is, I created a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L9gubqvy/3/), "running" the code if the output/result window is small, I see the 50%:50%. Resizing the output window and make it larger, everything is okay, the 50%:50% is okay, but making the output window smaller, the chart does not resize properly.

I saw some solutions with `$(window).resize();`. In my case, I tried to use the `outerHeight`, but the values only changes if I make the screen size bigger. So I found this solution which works:

```
$('#chart').highcharts().setSize(
  $(".wrapper").width() / 2, $('#chart').highcharts().height, doAnimation = true
);
```

But is there also a solution which does not need to use JavaScript, only HTML and CSS?

Comment: Instead of using JSFiddle, you can add your code directly in StackOverflow using StackOverflow Code Snippet: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should be done with just **CSS**... no resizing functions.

try adding `position:absolute` to your chart css property

The new **css** for `#chart` would look like this:

```
#chart {
    display: table-cell;
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
}
```

I think this is the effect you want.

### **[Check my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dalper01/0xmf9h6d)**

**note:** I removed all resizing **Javascript**

---

### Follow Up:

If you need to resize Highcharts on window resize with animation, you can do it with this syntax.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    height = $(window).height()
    width = $(window).width() / 2
    $("#chart").highcharts().setSize(width, height, doAnimation = true);
});
```

I think this is more what you wanted using the Highchart `setSize` method with animation instead of ***CSS***)

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vmvkahc)

Comment: But how can I vertically center the legend part on the right with your solution? ``vertical-align: middle`` does not work.

Comment: @Tim, in order to make `vertical-align: middle` work with `position:absolute;`, you must set height to an absolute value. I update my Fiddle to demonstrate. This is far from a perfect solution, but hopefully gives you enough of what you want.

Comment: Okay, this works and it is vertically centered if I set for ``.legend`` and ``#chart`` the same height.

Comment: @Tim, I created a new Fiddle using Highchart's setSize method on window resize event. I think this is more what you wanted.

Comment: In Highcharts 4.1.5 $("#chartId").highcharts() is coming back undefined. Has it changed again?

Comment: @IcedDante, Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: It was a goof on my part- sorry

Answer (score 5):

svg image prevents the `table-cell` to get smaller. Solution for this is:

```
.highcharts-container, .highcharts-container svg {
     width: 100% !important;
}
```

See the example http://jsfiddle.net/FzXEM/9/

There are other ways to make the chart resize correctly like using `float: left` or `position: absolute` but then there are other problems and you can only use `vertical-align` in table or inline layouts.

Answer (score 3):

Instaed of table cell, why you cannot use default divs with the `float:left` option?

```
.wrapper {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}
.element {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
#chart {
    width: 100%;
}
.legend {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L9gubqvy/4/

Comment: The legend needs to be vertically centered to the chart, that is the reason why I used ``table-cell``, so I can use ``vertical-align: middle;``.

Comment: You can use a position absolute, top 50%, and negative margin top

Comment: Yes, this can be done if I would know the height of the vertically aligned container, but I don't, so I can not use this method.

Comment: In the jquery you have a funciton height() so use it and call css() with half of height value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q66hqf33/)

The trick is to add two CSS properties:

- The wrapper `element` gets a `position: relative;`
- The chart div `chart` gets a `position:absolute;`

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but I have tried everything else and this was the only way which fixed resizing problems when shrinking the height of the chart. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
For me, use perfect.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
}

#chart {
  width: 100%;
}

.legend {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

$(window).resize(function() {

        $('#chart').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9gubqvy/9/

Answer (score 0):

try to use this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9gubqvy/6/)**

i am not sure how much it will help you, i have just used Highcharts some of the functionality.

**Note:** Resize the window of jsfiddle and run it will adjust according to the window i am not sure why it is behaving like this

**Html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">
<div id="container" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
        });
    });
```

CSS // i am not passing any css

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Please refer this link where Highchart is responsive **http://jsfiddle.net/2gtpA/show/**

Comment: No, it does not help me. I will need a custom legend on the right side of the chart which should be vertically-aligned. You only display a chart.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not quite sure why your chart was not resizing properly. But I have a way to do this without resizing in JS, *assuming you can set the height of your wrapper div*.

First of all, you really shouldn't style your elements as tables if you are not using tabular data; I removed this from your CSS. Secondly, if you want your legend centered, it really should be within a separate element that is alongside the chart; each should be wrapped in the same kind of div. Normally I'd call this a column, but since you're already using .element, that works too. These will each be floated to the left, with a width of 50%, and a height of 100% (this is important, because we can't center the legend vertically unless its parent has a height defined.

Then we have a child div inside the second .element, which is given the .legend class. Now we can more easily position it within that space. Since you don't know the height of the legend, you can't use a negative margin of 50%. Instead, you can use a [CSS3 transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). It looks like this:

```
.legend {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; /* relative to parent */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%); /* relative to the element itself */
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ala8727/nyb8eu18/1/)

This works well because the position is based on the parent element (or the closest ancestor with a defined position, but in this case, that would be the parent), and the transform is based on the element itself. So this will work regardless of the legend's height, your chart will resize properly, and you don't need to use JS to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use any JS code.
If you want the charts to become responsive, here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/L9gubqvy/12/

Here's the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
.wrapper:after {
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    content:" ";
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
.element {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
#chart {
    width: 100%;
}
.legend {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

PS: I'm having trouble posting the code using StackOverflow Code Snippet. I'll update the code later on.