# Highcharts: Chart does not resize properly by making the screen smaller in mozilla

Tags: css, highcharts, mozilla

I am using Highcharts 5.0.10, I met the problem like the topic
[Highcharts: Chart does not resize properly by making the screen smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934907/highcharts-chart-does-not-resize-properly-by-making-the-screen-smaller)
and I follow the below answer

> svg image prevents the table-cell to get smaller. Solution for this is:

```
.highcharts-container, .highcharts-container svg {
 width: 100% !important;}
```

> See the example http://jsfiddle.net/FzXEM/9/
>
> There are other ways to make the chart resize correctly like using
>   float: left or position: absolute but then there are other problems
>   and you can only use vertical-align in table or inline layouts.

it works fine in Chrome and IE, but doesn't effected in Mozilla. So my question is how to make it workable in Mozilla too? only do something in CSS.

Comment: Maybe try: http://jsfiddle.net/m6vdyjwd/

Comment: thanks for your reply. here in your example use a window resize function to set the new width and height in js. but if in Chrome or IE, don't need this function and works fine. and in Mozilla without the function the chart can't resize automatically. So how can I do something only in CSS to make it workable in Mozilla?